# Where observable object stored in memory in browser?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactive-programming, observer-pattern

When we create observable object ,is it stored in heap ?

Is it wrapper object around source of data,either an array object or single value or events *(it wraps source into an object and store it in memory)* as a resource in memory?

Does it *(observable object)* send signal to operating system ,interrupts command to perform specific action according to data received and pushes callback function on execution stack after current event loop?

///**EDITED**///
Objects which are observables (that Rxjs library creates)

Comment: About *every* object is stored in heap.

Comment: What do you mean by "source of data"? "events" is not an object. And what "observable objects" are you talking about, some library's `Observable` instances? No, they don't send any signals to the OS.

Comment: Observable object (source of data), when we create observable and subscribe it (Rxjs library)

Answer (score 1):

Observables are, as all userland javascript object, stored in the heap.

It is a wrapper around the source, in memory terms, in the same way as you can wrap a object in another object:

```
let object = { somekey: 'somevalue' };
let wrapper = { object: object }; // We just "wrapped" object
```

In response to your question about the timing, the OS and possible interrupts: No. Observables are still inside javascript, so work with javascript concurrency. They don't break free from the event loop in any way.

Observables are, basically, an abstraction around event listeners. You can make an observable from events like `document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {})`. When you make an observable that uses that event as source, it will be called as soon as the event listener gets called, there is not special or magic timing for Observables.